# Change the default settings of File/Append operator in 2.8

Tags: python, customization, linked-data, append, file-browser

I'd like to have operators's File/Append option **Localize All** uncheck by default.

I work in a studio environment where several artists(~10) will need to do this operation on a regular basis. 
I've found some solutions but none of which seems appropriate in my case :

I can set a default shortcut and tweak the operator settings, but that would mean force 10 people to always use the shortcut. It's like telling them to always uncheck the option but as they've got a lot of other stuff to think of it's an easy miss, and it's hard to fix the issues once you realize latter that it occurred.

I can also edit space_topbar.py and change the defaults . The thing is that we often update blender version, and that would be another step to make each time.

Are there some remaining options ?

Should I go and talk to the developers to change the settings, or submit a patch to space_topbar.py ? Does it makes sense ? I fear this could take a while before it gets implemented and from what I see this is really a matter of case were you want this option on by default or not.

Alternatively is it possible to overwrite the menu (via an addon) ? or replace bpy.ops.wm.append() with a tweaked version ?